# Running python script on multiple files

Tags: python, mysql, file

I have a python script that reads a file and extracts certain data from it, then stores the data in a dictionary, and finally inserts that into a mysql table. The first line of my code is where I enter in my filename:

```
filename = "examplelogfile"
```

which is a text file, and is later referred to as 'filename'. But I have to run this code on almost a thousand different files of this type, and I've moved all of these files to a certain server (I'm not running the script in terminal since I need to run it on the same server where the mysql database is located). What's the easiest way to run my code on all of the files?

Edit: I have tried this but it isn't giving me any output (it is supposed to print all the dictionaries):

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('~/Desktop/pythoncode/*logfile')
for filename in files:
    rest of code
    print dict
```

Comment: define  path without `~` or use in `os.path.expanduser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module to get all files like this:

```
import glob
path = 'C:/Users/telli/Desktop/Test Shapes/Shapes/Squares'
filenames = glob.glob(path + '/*.gif')
for filename in filenames:
    # Do something
```

Comment: Does the wildcard method work when I do not have a file extension? As seen in my question the format for the filenames is "somethinglogfile" but there is no extension.

Comment: You can ignore the extension using .endswith() with a short bit of logic beforehand. EDIT: Or just use the answer provided above.

Comment: Because all the file names end in the word logfile. The problem was actually the ~, so now it works.

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: filenames = glob.glob(path + '/*.txt') assuming your logfile is a text file